# How to create a deterministic wallet using bitcoinjs-lib

Tags: private-key, cryptography, bitcoinjs

I'm new to bitcoin technology, however, I'm trying to develop a web wallet using bitcoinjs-lib that works like that of blockchain.info. I've gone through the code samples on the github repo but couldn't make out the one I could us to create a deterministic wallet.
I intend to make the wallet users enter a long and strong password from which the private key can be generated from.

Any code sample or link would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

See Blockchain.info wallet source code
https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet-V3

Also check the bitcoinjs-lib's list of projects